# Connecting an existing sqlite database to Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Can someone guide me to connect an existing sqlite database with my android app??
I've tried many methods but neither works.

I followed this tutorial
https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

But it doesn't help me.

Comment: You should start with sharing what you've tried

Comment: @Gsk Basically I followed this tutorial....https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: The example from android docs is so much better: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java

Comment: @Gleb thanks... will try it